# how to get Campaign status (campaign budget constrained/ Limited by Budget) using google adword API

Tags: google-ads-api, adwords-budgetservice

I am using google Adwords API to know my campaign status , here i am trying to know stats of all my previous day campaign which are limited by budget. 
                                    for the same what i have done is - 
                                     reportType = 'CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT'
                                    $selector->fields = 'CampaignName','CampaignStatus', 'Clicks', 'Cost'.

currently as the result i am getting all the campaign those are either Enabled of Paused none of them are shown as Limited By Budget even though there are some campaign with limited budget in my Adwords account.
i am attaching screen shot with report type and contents fields on it.
[campaign stsus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKyD7.png) 
Please guide me to get desired output.
Thanks

[limited by budget error - cost is 112 only though budget is 300](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JhQB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not "Limited By Budget" field in that report. Maybe you can take the cost and the budget and see if it's limited

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! i am unable to find any option for budget, though there is option for BudgetId only, so problem remains same for me.

Comment: It is the amount field

Comment: can u tell me one more thing - how much difference i should consider to mark a campaign as Limited by Budget , in most of the cases amount is lesser and cost is higher but  for some case it is not .  one example i would like to share :- i am editing my question to share screen shot please have a look of that .

Comment: Maybe 90%, It depends, whatever you want... I can not find anything about that on internet, some people say 80%... I would say 90%

Comment: very difficult to say about it, my ads are limited by budget when the campaign having budget left for 3-4 more clicks, I. e. more than 50 % of the budget.